# iBeacon: Get advertisement package faster

Tags: swift, ibeacon, estimote

In my app I get the information of the beacons with CoreLocation and and the LocationManager. 
I've set the advertising interval of the beacons to 200ms.
Is it possible to call the didRangeBeacons delegate method faster, so that i get the values of the advertising package according to the advertising interval of the beacon?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot alter the frequency of the `didRangeBeacons:inRegion` callback, which is 1 Hz regardless of the beacon advertising frequency.

**You can get callbacks for each beacon advertisement (every 200 ms in your case) using `CoreBluetooth` APIs**, but there are a couple of restrictions:

1. It will not work with iBeacon transmissions as [iOS blocks access to iBeacon advertisement data](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html) in `CoreBluetooth`.  You can use [AltBeacons](http://altbeacon.org/), which are iBeacon compatible, and get the more frequent updates with those.  You can buy [beacons that send out both iBeacon and AltBeacon transmissions](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/collections/all).
2. It will only work in the foreground.  You cannot get Bluetooth LE manufacturer advertisements in the background on iOS.

Full disclosure: I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks which sponsors the open source AltBeacon standard.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your answer. Based on your answer I still have some questions. Are the physical AltBeacons usable with iOS and Android? Do I have to use the Radius Networks SDKs for building iOS or Android Apps? DIn my case it is important, that i can identify the different beacons and get the rssi values in a acceptably time for some indoor navigation research. Can i use the AltBeacons also with CoreLocation or rather does the broadcast the normal iBeacon standard too?

Comment: You do not have to use RadiusNetworks SDKs to use AltBeacons.  You can use CoreBluetooth by itself.  The RadBeacon product line transmits interleaved iBeacon and AltBeacon advertisements with the same identifiers, so you can detect the iBeacon with CoreLocation and the AltBeacon with CoreBluetooth.   I have used these beacons for indoor location as well, using CoreBluetooth to get RSSI updates at 10 Hz.  Works like a champ!

Comment: And, yes, you can use AltBeacon transmissions on Android, too.  The standard Android bluetooth scanning APIs on 4.3+ will pick them up.  And you can use this open source SDK to decode them if you wish:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/

Comment: That sounds good :) Which information will i get with CoreBluetooth from the AltBeacons? Is it possible to get the UUID, Minor, Major, RSSI and TXPower? How do i set the frequency with CoreBluetooth to 10 Hz or how can i trigger the CBCentralManager, that he will do this? So that are all of my question. Thanks in advance.