# Detect an AltBeacon with CoreBluetooth

Tags: swift, ibeacon, altbeacon

i want to detect an altBeacon (transmitted by an Android Smartphone with the QuickBeacon App) with CoreBluetooth and Swift.

But when I search for a specific UUID the delegate method is not being called.

```
   func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!){

    if (central.state == .PoweredOff) {
        println("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off")
    }
    else if (central.state == .PoweredOn) { 
        var UUIDObj:NSArray! = [CBUUID(string: "2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")]
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(UUIDObj as [AnyObject], options: nil)
        NSLog("Scanning started"); }}
```

Normally this method should be called

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
```

When i change the Beacon Format to "iBeacon" it also don't work.
Does anybody know how i can get the advertising values of the AltBeacon and iBeacon standard with coreBluetooth?

Update:

When i search for all peripheral devices i get this information from my AltBeacon:

> in DidDiscoverPeripheral
>   AdvertisementData: [kCBAdvDataIsConnectable: 0]
>   RSSI: -47
>   Peripheral Name: nil , State: (Enum Value) , Services:nil, RSSI:nil,ID: <__NSConcreteUUID 0x17002edc0> A91CBF8C-DA69-B2FB-1A9A-CDDB60A48209 , Description:

But the UUID does not match with the given ID :(

Comment: If you scan for peripheral without giving specific Service UUID, do you fid it?

Comment: It seems that AltBeacon doesn't advertise its services UUID. So, you can't scanForPeripheral filtering on a specific service UUID if it does broadcast one.

Comment: I broadcast the beacon signal with the QuickBeacon App of Radius Networks with my Nexus 6. Is it possible that the app or the Nexus 6 does not broadcast the right package?

Comment: It seems so. Since we can read in your logs: "Services:nil", it doesn't broadcast services. It may have the service, but doesn't broadcast it.

Comment: Do you think that a real AltBeacon (for example a RadBeacon) would broadcast the "right" advertisement data so that i could define the region by UUID?

Comment: A "real beacon" shouldn't be read with CoreBluetooth, but with CoreLocation. iOS separate both case.

Comment: But with CoreLocation I can scan only at 1 Hz. With CoreBluetooth it would be possible to scan with 10 Hz. This is the reason why I want to use CoreBluetooth. Do you have another solution?

Comment: No. A Beacon only advertise its UUID, Minor, Major, etc. The only way is to use CoreLocation. Even if it's BLE, Apple separates it, and since it analyze it, it won't allow you to find it with CoreBluetooth.

Comment: But in this post davidyound told something different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373723/ibeacon-get-advertisement-package-faster

Comment: Seems that AltBeacon is not a real iBeacon, and is between both. So that may explains why you should be able to find it with CoreBluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer a part of your question: The `CBCentralManager`'s delegate methods (e.g. `func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!)`) are only called if you instantiate the manager with a queue, i.e. using `init(delegate:queue:)` or `init(delegate:queue:options:)` instead of just `init()`...

Comment: The func 'centralManagerDidUpdateState' works with an normal init when I do not specify the service UUID. This is not the problem