# How to get iBeacon adverts faster in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

Is the answer to this question [iBeacon: Get advertisement package faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373723/ibeacon-get-advertisement-package-faster)
still up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but alas, it is the correct one.

You can't alter the callback frequency of the CoreBluetooth discovery APIs. This is also true for the CoreLocation APIs.

Besides, even if you could, you'd cane the user's battery so much by doing so that it would be undesirable.